# java split keep the separator as independent array element

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split the string

```
Actual #keys: {}, Estimated #keys:{}, Err%: {}"
```

to

```
[{}, Actual #keys: , {}, Estimated #keys:, {}, Err%: , {}]
```

I try use

```
str.split("(?=\\b\\{\\})")
```

but its result is

```
[{}Actual #keys: {}, Estimated #keys:{}, Err%: {}]
```

Comment: its array instead doing like above join your as String then you can split it as you want

Comment: Where did the extra `{}` come from?

Comment: This is doable (although not as easily as in python, which given your regex I assume you already know this), except for the magic appearance of `{}` as the first element. Not even python can make stuff appear in the split result that wasn't in the input. Are you sure the leading `{}` is meant to be there? If so, how do you suppose it can be created by splitting?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `{}` is separator then `(?<=.)(?=\\{}))|((?<=\\{})(?=.))` should work. This means - split between any char and separator or between separator and any char.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.StringTokenizer`, which has an option to return the delimiters.